# XDocument memory usage problem

Tags: .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a small application that builds up a xml document using XDocument. However, after a while the app is using more than 1gb ram.

So I was wondering if there is anyway to make XDocument use the disk instead of in-memory. For example by opening a StreamWriter and save it to a file on the go.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you building it up?  What do you do with it once its built?

Comment: Informational: I loaded up a 1.4GB xml into XDocument and memory usage climbed up to 2.4GB (there WAS about 30% whitespace in the original file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you refer to the .net [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx), you can instead use a [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) ([tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d1k42hb.aspx)). The XmlWriter can be attached to any stream you like by using the [XmlWriter.Create()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.create.aspx) method.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that your document is so large as to consume 1 GB of memory?

Using a memory profiling tool such as [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index.htm) might help you discover what objects are remaining in memory.

Comment: Actually, it's really that big and I didn't realize it. I suppose I'll have to go with the stream solution :) Thanks.

Comment: I actually just checked and some of the xml files are over 300mb in size, so I guess the x xml classes has some overhead so the memory usage seems right.

Comment: 300Mb XML files - are you sure XML is the best format for this data?